# How to print arguments passed to configure script?

Tags: bash, shell, configure

I'm trying to print arguments passed to a ./configure script. Calling 'echo' on $BASH_ARGV will just print the last set of arguments. For example if I run:

./configure --enable-foo --enable-bar

echo $BASH_ARGV will print only "--enable-bar"

How do I print all the arguments? Thanks!

Comment: BASH_ARGV is clearly bash specific. Configure scripts should be Bourne shell compliant.

Comment: How would it be done via Bourne shell?

Comment: Can you get them from `config.log`? I've just checked and the arguments are displayed there.

Comment: Yes I could use cat and grep to get the arguments, however this seems very "hackish." I'm interested to know how configure was able to save the arguments there in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variable called ac_configure_args that contains what I need. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $@ and $* to refer to parameters.

`echo "$@";` should do it. A little more information [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters.html?ca=drs-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Echoing $@ will just output 'dummy make'

Comment: are you using the double quotes?

Comment: In this case, quotes aren't needed.

Comment: it is usefull if the parameters have blanks. But this doesn't seem the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an array, you need to do this to get all the elements:

```
echo ${BASH_ARGV[@]}
```

or use a loop to iterate over them.

Note: they'll be output in reverse order.